# json in select tags

Tags: jquery

i will come straight to the point i have this code in html

```
<select id ="list" name = "items[]"></select>
<select id ="list" name = "items[]"></select>
<select id ="list" name = "items[]"></select>
```

in jquery i have

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $.getJSON('product_json.php', function(data) {
        var select = $('#list');
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            $('<option/>').attr('value', val.PRODUCTID)
                  .html('ID ' + val.PRODUCTID)
                  .appendTo(select);
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```

i am getting json data for first select tag but dont in other 2 select tags, i want the same json data in all 3 select tags using same id. in my example id = "list" thanks

Answer (score 5):

### **IDs must be unique!**

Consider using classes instead:

```
<select class="list" name="items[]"></select>
<select class="list" name="items[]"></select>
<select class="list" name="items[]"></select>

<script>
    var select = $(".list");
    // ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have several tags with the same ID. You could use classes instead. Also you shouldn't be using spaces between attribute names and values:

```
<select id="list1" name="items[]"></select>
<select id="list2" name="items[]"></select>
<select id="list3" name="items[]"></select>
```

OR

```
<select class="list" name="items[]"></select>
<select class="list" name="items[]"></select>
<select class="list" name="items[]"></select>
```

Comment: The spaces make absolutely no difference to the browser.

Comment: @Blazemonger Well it is definitively against the HTML/XHTML specification, see W3C!

Answer (score 0):

**ID**'s must be unique, a corrected version of your code would be:

```
<select class ="list" name = "items[]"></select>
<select class ="list" name = "items[]"></select>
<select class ="list" name = "items[]"></select>
```

and in jquery:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $.getJSON('product_json.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            $('<option/>').attr('value', val.PRODUCTID)
                  .html('ID ' + val.PRODUCTID)
                  .appendTo('.list');
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
```